# Скриншот внутри формы C#

Tags: c#

Я пытаюсь написать программу распознающую текст со скриншота, но мне нужно что бы программа делала скриншот не полного экрана а отдельной части. Для себя я сделал вывод что можно реализовать его через рамку формы(сделать так что бы скрин делался за формой). Я это реализовал но столкнулся с проблемой что скрин делается по размерам формы и берет начальную точку в центре формы. Вот вопрос - как можно сделать так что бы он делал скрин внутри формы по беря во внимание только контуры формы(т.е бордюры формы являлись для него ограничителем), либо как сделать что бы начальная точка начиналась с нижнего правого угла.

```
Bitmap screen = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height)
using(Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(screen))
{
gr.CopyFromScreen(this.PointToScreen(Point.Empty),Point.Empty, this.Size)
}
screen.Save(path + name)
```

Приблизительно такой код

Comment: [DisplayRectangle](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.displayrectangle?view=netcore-3.1), [ClientRectangle](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle?view=netcore-3.0) - используйте одного из этих свойств, чтобы получить размеры формы без бордюров. В чём различие между ними: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34453825/5045688

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую. Но ради интереса, возможно ли изменить начало координат? Я новичок в программировании поэтому ищу ответы на такие вопросы

Comment: @МихаилБорзенков координаты всегда можно перевести в ту систему, которая будет удобна вам, с помощью формул

Comment: Т. к. вы делаете скриншот собственной формы, то, возможно, проще будет использовать метод [DrawToBitmap](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap?view=netcore-3.0)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я делаю скриншот не формы та то что за ней. Т.е есть рамка формы, за формой есть текстовый документ с надписями, и мне нужно что бы я поставил рамку формы на текст, растянул рамку формы и мне скринило текст в документе. Я возможно непонятно объяснил, так что приму любые ответы

Comment: Ok, понял. Однако, с чем проблема-то? Ваш код правильный, делает скриншот в нужных координатах. Возможно, нужно сделать прозрачную форму? В конструкторе формы напишите `TransparencyKey = BackColor;`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov проблема в том что он делает скрин в размер формы, но при этом он смещает место скрина влево вверх и получается что он захватывает не то что нужно. Проблема вызвана тем что Point.Empty  находятся посередине формы и от них метод скриншота берет отсчет высоты и ширины. А форма уже прозрачная, я еще при инцилизации задал этот параметр.

Comment: Point.Empty - координаты 0, 0 - верхний левый угол, но никак не середина. | Что такое `this` в вашем коде? Сама форма или какой-то другой контрол?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov this - сама форма, а на счет координат сам не понимаю почему они в центре хотя должны быть в верхнем левом углу